# What is the best way to schedule a sending-email task with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I would like to schedule a daily task : every day at 7 AM, I want an email to be sent (without human intervention).

I'm working on the RoR framework and I'm wondering what is the best way to do that?

I've heard about BackgrounDRB, OpenWFEru scheduler or things based on Cron, but I'm a newbie and don't understand which one is made for my need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another option is to create a rake task that is run by a cron job. 
To do this, create a file `some_file.rake` and put it in your `lib/tasks` folder. Your file might look like this:

Rails 2.x:

```
task :send_daily_mail, :needs => :environment do
    Model.send_daily_mail
end
```

Rails 3.x:

```
task :send_daily_mail => :environment do
    Model.send_daily_mail
end
```

Then use cron to execute it as often as you like:

```
cd /path/to/app && /usr/bin/rake send_daily_mail
```

Note you might need to put `RAILS_ENV=production` in your crontab if your app is in development mode by default.

Comment: I have a strange problem with this:
when I execute "cd /path/to/app && /usr/local/bin/rake send_daily_mail" from command line, it works. But when crontab tries to execute it, I have the error "/usr/local/bin/rake:9:in `require': No such file to load-- rubygems(LoadError)" from /usr/local/bin/rake:9"

Comment: Cron tasks run by default without the benefit of the users full login environment. The crontab that worked for me was: */5 * * * * bash --login -c 'cd /path/to/app && rake send_daily_mail'

Answer (score 7):

I was impressed by (and plan to try) the [rufus-scheduler](http://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/tree/master) gem discussed [in this blog post](http://intridea.com/2009/2/13/dead-simple-task-scheduling-in-rails?blog=company)

He describes something like this:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new  

scheduler.every("1m") do  
   DailyDigest.send_digest!  
end
```

..which seems pretty simple. I wonder how easy it would be to add HTML-based configuration?

Comment: so? Did you try it, what did you think?

Answer (score 2):

BackgroundRB is what I use and it works perfect. I have several emails being sent, generated by BackgroundRB. I also have other tasks as well. Because it enables both scheduled tasks and asynchronous tasks (tasks that take longer than the normal client/server response cycle).

I use it and I am very happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class method to one of your models that will handle this for you.  Now try to execute that method using the runner script

```
./script/runner "MyModel.send_daily_mail" RAILS_ENV=production
```

Ensure everything works ok.  If it does, then we need to make the command work universally by setting up the path to the project properly.

```
cd /path/to/my/rails/project && ./script/runner "MyModel.send_daily_mail" RAILS_ENV=production
```

Now change to any random directiry and run that command. If it runs properly, run `crontab -e` and insert the command in there setup to run daily at 7AM.  There are a ton of explanation about the cron format on there if you google for them and should be pretty simple to figure out.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Is it possible to manage it from a specific file (like lib/tasks/send_mail.rb) rather than in a model's method?

Answer (score 0):

Go with a rake task and cron job, as the accepted answer already says. However, note that, updating the cron file itself is a manual task. That may be fine if you are not changing it during development. Otherwise, here how you can let Capistrano do it for you: http://push.cx/2008/deploying-crontab-with-your-rails-app