# Ruby on Rails - Users Scheduling Tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, scheduled-tasks

I am working on an application which people can sign up to and schedule tasks to be done.

When the user schedules a task they enter a date and time. I want the application to wake up and send an email to the user at the date and time they have entered.

I am unsure what gems/plugins to use in rails to achieve this, anyone have a suggestion?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) should do the trick. It allows you to schedule tasks to run at a particular time. All you need to do is schedule a function that sends an email.

Comment: this one was the closest to what I needed but I found resque afterwards which is good.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Run a cron job every minute that runs a rake task that checks the database for any un-run tasks in the past.

This way if your system goes down (hint: it will) when you bring it back
up the cronjob will pick up the slack left behind.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a [backgroundrb](http://backgroundrb.rubyforge.org/scheduling/).
Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553648/what-is-the-best-way-to-schedule-a-sending-email-task-with-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 0):

The Unix 'at' command is also useful.  Just execute a shell that calls 'at'.