# scheduled tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler

In my rails app I would like to notify the application users at a future time they select on the interface. I am using rufus-scheduler for annual notifications but I don't know how to use it at a specific time a user picks.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Users Scheduling Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210011/ruby-on-rails-users-scheduling-tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Please go through on readme of gem:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.at '24h' do
  # do something at a given point in time
end
```

So what you can do, you can make a rake task that will run daily and it will check If there is any tomorrow date of action of user to run anything then It can create a delayed job for that time then It will execute

Comment: Thanks. My problem is I don't know the time now. The user picks it and is saved in a database. So, I am looking for a method of creating a queue from user input

Comment: So what you can do, you can make a rake task that will run daily and it will check If there is any tomorrow date of user to run anything then It can create a delayed job for that time then It will execute

Comment: Thanks. I think I can do it using rufus-scheduler. Running a daily task to check if there are notifications that should be sent. Thanks, once more

Answer (score 1):

By reading the previous comments i feel you can do the following

1.Write a rake task to get all the notification to be sent on the next day and insert the same into a new table(its should contain notification_id and user_id,status) where you can track it .

2.Run the above rake task every day using rufus scheduler .

3.Write another rake task which will take the notification_id and user_id from the table and send notification via mail or your notification center and then update the status in the table,this also should be scheduled in Rufus scheduler

Hope the flow will be of your help,this approach will give you ability and flexibility on the notification sent and reports based on status can also be generated over notification

Answer (score 0):

You can run a task at a specific time by using `scheduler.at`. Example:

```
scheduler.at '2030/12/12 23:30:00' do
  # do something at a given point in time
end
```

See https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler for the full details.

Comment: But I don't know the time beforehand. It comes from the user. How can I add the user input to a queue?